# How to have a firstname validation in iOS swift4?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have a first name validation to be done in swift4 which is in a `UITextField`. The thing is that:

1. The Firstname should start with a letter and end with a letter,
2. No trailing and leading whitespace.
3. It can have spaces between them, can contain dot.
4. should be between 7 and 18 characters.

Currently i am having the following validation in the UITextField

```
public func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let STRING_ACCEPTABLE_CHARACTERS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    switch textField {
    case firstName:
        print("firstname")
        if string == " " {
            return false
        } else {
            let cs = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn: STRING_ACCEPTABLE_CHARACTERS).inverted
            let filtered = string.components(separatedBy: cs).joined(separator: "")
            return (string == filtered)
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Any idea how to implement the following conditions. Right now I am disabling the space and only accepts the alphabets.

Any help will be very much appreciated

Comment: Could you please also think about non-English names that contain other characters? For example `"María"` or `"François"`? `a-z` characters are not the only letters that exist. I am not saying how will your validation fail for asian name. My first name is even shorter than 7 characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this func for short and clean way

```
func isValid(testStr:String) -> Bool {
    guard testStr.count > 7, testStr.count < 18 else { return false }

    let predicateTest = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", "^(([^ ]?)(^[a-zA-Z].*[a-zA-Z]$)([^ ]?))$")
    return predicateTest.evaluate(with: testStr)
}
```

**Test cases**

```
isValid(testStr: " MyNameIsDahiya") // Invalid, leading space
isValid(testStr: "MyNameIsDahiya ") // Invalid, trailing space
isValid(testStr: " MyNameIsDahiya ") // Invalid, leading & trailing space
isValid(testStr: "1MyNameIsDahiya") // Invalid, Leading num
isValid(testStr: "MyNameIsDahiya1") // Invalid, trailing num
isValid(testStr: "1MyNameIsDahiya1") // Invalid, leading & trailing num
isValid(testStr: "MyName") // Invalid, length below 7
isValid(testStr: "MyNameIsDahiyaBlahhblahh") // Invalid, length above 18

isValid(testStr: "MyNameIsDahiya") // Valid,
isValid(testStr: "Mr. Dahiya") // Valid,
```

**Playground Test**

[image]

> Edit

Try this below regex:

```
(?mi)^[a-z](?!(?:.*\.){2})(?!(?:.* ){2})(?!.*\.[a-z])[a-z. ]{5,16}[a-z]$
```

It will validate all the conditions and length also.

Comment: will "Mr Dahiya" will be valid?

Comment: @ElizabethMoly Yeah, check last option.

Comment: Thanks a lot. is it possible to accept only single space between them? because "mr(6 white space in between)y" is also getting accepted

Comment: Thanks a lot I will check and let you know

Answer (score 2):

You can check the two conditions when you are taking the value from `UITextField` which are:

1. Firstname should start and end with a letter
2. Trimming whitespaces at the end.

And the rest conditions can be done inside `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` like below:

```
let STRING_ACCEPTABLE_CHARACTERS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz. "
    switch textField {
    case firstName:
        print("firstname")
        //Condition for always accepting backcspaces
        if string == "" {
            return true
        }
        //Condition for restricting space at the begining
        else if textField.text?.count == 0 && string == " " {
            return false
        }
        //Condition for restricing user from entering more than 18 letters
        else if (textField.text?.count)! > 17 {
          return false
        }
        //Condition for only accepting the alphabets.
        else {
            let cs = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn: STRING_ACCEPTABLE_CHARACTERS).inverted
            let filtered = string.components(separatedBy: cs).joined(separator: "")
            return (string == filtered)
        }
```

For checking the minimum number of letters, trimming whitespaces at the end and starting and ending with a letter with below conditions inside a **Button's click** or something equivalent to it:

```
//Trimming whitespaces at the end
let firstname = firstName.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)

let letters = NSCharacterSet.letters

let prefix = String((firstname?.first)!)
let suffix = String((firstname?.last)!)

//Checking if First Character is letter
if let _ = prefix.rangeOfCharacter(from: letters) {
    print("letters found")
} else {
    print("letters not found")
}

//Checking if Last Character is letter
if let _ = suffix.rangeOfCharacter(from: letters) {
    print("letters found")
} else {
    print("letters not found")
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: it sounds nice but i would like to validate when the user stops editing and moves to next uitextfield . How to achieve that?

Comment: Do that in didEndEditing then!

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to validate First name with your conditions.

I'm not an expert in regex, but [here you can see an example](https://regex101.com/r/yF0hvS/3)

```
^[a-zA-Z](?:[a-zA-Z\.\s][^\n]*)[a-zA-Z]$
```

This regex will return you full matches. You can check, if any matches returned string is valid.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27880650/swift-extract-regex-matches) with example of usage regex in Swift.

Number of string characters you can check using Swift, like:

```
if string.count > 7 && string.count < 18 {
    //String valid
}
```