# String extension for matching regular expression

Tags: swift, swift2, swift4, nsregularexpression, swift4.2

I have 2 functions written in Swift 2, but Apple forced me to migrate to Swift 4 and I can't fix the functions.

```
extension String {
    func stringsMatchingRegularExpression(expression: String) -> [String] {
        if let range = self.rangeOfString(expression, options: NSString.CompareOptions.RegularExpressionSearch, range: nil, locale: nil) {
            return [self[range]] + self[range.endIndex..<self.endIndex].stringsMatchingRegularExpression(expression)
        }
        return []
    }

    func stringsMatchingRegularExpressionLarge(expression: String) -> [String] {
        var result = [String]()
        var currentRange = self.characters.indices
        while let range = self.rangeOfString(expression, options: NSString.CompareOptions.RegularExpressionSearch, range: currentRange, locale: nil) {
            result.append(self[range])
            currentRange.startIndex = range.endIndex
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

The return of the first function is the problem I can't fix it.
The 3rd line is `if let range = self.range(of: expression, options: NSString.CompareOptions.regularExpression, range: nil, locale: nil){` in Swift 4

In 2nd function I don't know how .characters migrating.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27880650/swift-extract-regex-matches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.characters` are gone. You can use the string itself directly.

Change `self.characters.indices` to `self.indices`

Change `self.rangeOfString(expression, options: NSString.CompareOptions.RegularExpressionSearch, range: nil, locale: nil)` to `self.range(of: expression, options: .regularExpression, range: nil, locale: nil)`

And lastly, you can use `NSRegularExpression` instead of recursively call the function, but note that it can `throw` some errors, so you should handle it somehow. Use this extension:

```
extension String {
    func stringsMatchingRegularExpression(expression regex: String) throws -> [String] {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex)
        let results = regex.matches(in: self,
                                    range: NSRange(self.startIndex..., in: self))
        return results.map {
            String(self[Range($0.range, in: self)!])
        }
    }
}
```

### - More Swifty-Style:

```
extension String {

    func matching(expression regex: @autoclosure () throws -> NSRegularExpression) rethrows -> [String] {
        let results = try regex().matches(in: self, range: NSRange(self.startIndex..., in: self))
        return results.map {
            String(self[Range($0.range, in: self)!])
        }
    }

    func matching(pattern regexPattern: String) throws -> [String] {
        return try self.matching(expression: NSRegularExpression(pattern: regexPattern))
    }
}
```

Comment: What about large expression ?

Comment: I believe this can handle both.

Comment: I added some more convenient codes. check it out if you like.