# What is the correct length: argument to provide to NSRange for NSRegularExpression using a (Swift) String?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm confused on how to use the `NSRegularExpression` class in Swift, especially the `:length` parameter of `NSRange`.

Some tutorials say that NSRegularExpression should only be applied to NSString instances, while others say it's OK to apply it to (Swift) string instances as long as you provide `utf8.count` or `utf16.count` to `:length` parameter of `NSRange`:

```
var str : String = "#tweak #wow #gaming" 
if let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "#[a-z0-9]+", options: .caseInsensitive) {
    regex.matches(in: str, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: str.utf8.count)).map {
        print(str.substring(with: $0.range))
    }
}
```

The following are quotes from this [source](https://learnappmaking.com/regular-expressions-swift-string/):

> Due to the way strings are handled differently in Swift and
>   Objective-C, you will need to provide the NSRange instance with a
>   string length from NSString, and not from String.
>
> This is, roughly speaking, because NSString uses fixed-width encoding
>   and String uses variable-width encoding.

Furthermore, is the following documentation really the best Apple can do with respect to documenting the `NSRegularExpression` class in Swift?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsregularexpression

I'd at least expect a list of properties and methods of the class, but it only show some examples. Is there any more elaborate documentation?

Comment: Related: [Swift extract regex matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27880650/swift-extract-regex-matches).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We would use the utf16 count. But, it is best to let the framework do this conversion for you. To convert a `Range<String.Index>` to a `NSRange`:

```swift
let range = NSRange(string.startIndex..., in: string)
```

And to convert `NSRange` to `Range<String.Index>`:

```swift
let range = Range(nsRange, in: string)
```

Thus, putting that together:

```swift
let string = "#tweak #wow #gaming" 
if let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "#[a-z0-9]+", options: .caseInsensitive) {
    let nsRange = NSRange(string.startIndex..., in: string)
    let strings = regex.matches(in: string, range: nsRange).compactMap {
        Range($0.range, in: string).map { string[$0] }
    }
    print(strings)
}
```

---

<strike>See WWDC 2017 [Efficient Interactions with Frameworks](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/244/?time=1548), which talks about (a) our historical use of UTF16 when dealing with ranges; and (b) the fact that we don’t have to do that any more.</strike>  [This video is no longer available.]

---

That having been said, nowadays we would retire the `NSRegularExpression` and use [Regex](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/regex), which eliminates the `NSRange` entirely:

```swift
let string = "#tweak #wow #gaming"
let strings = string.matches(of: /#[a-zA-Z0-9]+/)
    .map { string[$0.range] }
```

Or

```swift
let regex = /#[a-z0-9]+/
    .ignoresCase()

let strings = string.matches(of: regex)
    .map { string[$0.range] }
```

For more information, see WWDC 2022 video [Meet Swift Regex](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/110357/), and the related videos listed on that page.

Comment: I'm new to iOS dev. Will you make your answer more elaborate, and also comment whether a better documentation exist? Also, is Apple using UTF16 instead of UTF8, which is the standard?

Comment: Both UTF16 and UTF8 are standards, but UTF8 is more common (e.g. for web services and the like). But it doesn’t matter which is the “better” standard, the question is which is the correct way to convert `NSRange` to `String.Range` and back, and for that, you must use UTF16, regardless. Or, as I’ve said, to excise your code of cryptic UTF choices, use these convenience initializers, which eliminate the guesswork. I’ll dig around and see if I can find references for you.

Comment: @Shuzheng - FYI [the UTF16View documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/utf16view) describes how UTF16 is used for indexing within `NSString` (and `NSRange` is basically a range of indexes within a `NSString`).

Comment: Thanks you, I can't find any official references for NSRegularExpression in Swift. I guess, Apple assumes that we are all coming from Objective-C. Last question, are Swift strings encoded as UTF16, while Objective-C strings are encoded as ASCII?

Comment: @Shuzheng:  From [NSString](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring) (which is originally an Objective-C class and predates Swift): *“A string object presents itself as a sequence of UTF–16 code units.”* – Swift strings used UTF-16 (or ASCII) originally, but switched to UTF-8 in Swift 5. That should be considered an implementation detail.

Comment: @MartinR - I've also read something like that. But why is UTF16 then provided to NSRange length:, when we use UTF8?

Comment: @Shuzheng: NSRange  describes a range of characters in an NSString, and therefore counts UTF-16 code units. – You could of course ask: “Why does NSExpression take a (Swift) String argument for the string, but a (Foundation) NSRange for the range?” That is a good question. String/NSString are bridged/converted more or less automatically, but the corresponding ranges are not.

Comment: @MartinR - I guess UTF8 must be compatible with UTF16, like ASCII is compatible with UTF8. Otherwise, I cannot see how it makes sense to provide an UTF16 range (NSRange) to NSRegularExpression.matches(), which may operate on an UTF8 encoded Swift string?

Comment: @Shuzheng: No. `NSRegularExpression` is an Objective-C Foundation class and works with NSString and NSRange. The Swift string is automatically converted to NSString when passed to an Objective-C method.

Comment: @Rob - Don't you mean `Range<String.Index>` when you refer to `String.Range`? The latter type is not recognized on my system.

Comment: @Rob - Also, why don't you `NSRange(region: RangeExpression)` instead of the form  `NSRange(region: RangeExpression, in: StringProtocol)`?

Comment: Yes, I meant `Range` of `String.Index`. But, no, I meant `NSRange(_:in:)`, not `NSRange(_:)`. I quote from documentation/headers: “Although the Swift overlay updates many Objective-C methods to return native Swift indices and index ranges, some still return instances of `NSRange`. To convert an `NSRange` instance to a range of `String.Index`, use the `Range(_:in:)` initializer, which takes an `NSRange` and a string as arguments.” Also see the examples in that video.

Comment: The `NSRange(_:)` rendition is only used when building from a range of fixed width integers (e.g. code like `let nsRange = NSRange(1..<3)`). But that’s of no utility when converting a `Range<String.Index>` to `NSRange`...