# Swift: Getting range of text that includes emojis

Tags: ios, swift

I am using regex to remove certain substrings in a string and I am encountering situations where the range is shorter than the actual string's length when emojis are present in the string.

For example:

```
// Original string
1.30pm. Let’s eat  https://somedomain.com/vDYEvkSFqa 

//Expected end result
1.30pm. Let’s eat
```

However, what I'm getting is this result:

```
1.30pm. Let’s eat  a
```

Notice the extra "a" left behind.

I am using the below code, and it works well for strings without any emoji. But with emoji, the `range` obtained is too short.

```
func removeTwitterUrlInTweet(text: String) -> String {
    let pattern = "https://somedomain.com/.*"

    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: .caseInsensitive)
        let range = NSMakeRange(0, text.count)
        let modifiedText = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: text, options: [], range: range, withTemplate: "")
        return modifiedText

    } catch {
        Log("Tweet regex err: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return text
    }
}
```

My second attempt converts the string to `utf8` but crashes with index out of range.

```
func removeTwitterUrlInTweet(text: String) -> String {
    let pattern = "https://somedomain.com/.*"
    let string = String(describing: text.cString(using: .utf8))

    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: .caseInsensitive)
        let range = NSMakeRange(0, string.count)
        let modifiedText = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: text, options: [], range: range, withTemplate: "")
        return modifiedText
    } catch {
        Log("Tweet regex err: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return text
    }
}
```

How do I get the full range from the text that includes emojis?

Comment: `NSMakeRange(0, text.count)`=> `NSMakeRange(0, text.utf16.count)`? NSRegularExrepssion/NSSring counts are in UTF16.

Comment: @Larme Awesome that works!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57525620/what-is-the-correct-length-argument-to-provide-to-nsrange-for-nsregularexpressi https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46495365/using-nsregularexpression-produces-incorrect-ranges-when-emoji-are-present https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51436417/which-swift-character-count-should-i-use-when-interacting-with-nsstring-apis