# How do I uses addAttribute and NSRANGE in swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, nsattributedstring, nsrange, addattribute

Hi I'm trying to use `addAttribute` in Swift3.

I want set bold only IDNAME.

Here is what I am trying to this.

```
let boldUsername = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "IDNAME hi nice 2 meet you :D #HELLOW")


//            boldUsername.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont(name: "SFUIText-Bold", size: 14)!, range: (boldUsername.string as NSString).range(of: " "))

            boldUsername.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont(name: "SFUIText-Bold", size: 14)!, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: 5))
```

How do I get index of the IDNAME i.e different every time?

-> Is there a way to split space and get index?

Comment: Can you please explain "How do I get string count", what does it mean?

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32229033/6541007) ?

Comment: @NiravD I want get index of strings. e.g > "IDNAME hi ~~~" I is index 0. E is index 5. So How do I get the end of ID's index? Thanks for the reply

Comment: you means idname is run time name and you want the range of its. right?

Comment: @NiravD yeah right exactly. I'm making an comment view.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to do something like this.

```
let personName = "Black"
let wholeStr = "\(personName) hi nice 2 meet you :D #HELLOW"
let boldUsername = NSMutableAttributedString(string: wholeStr)
boldUsername.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont(name: "SFUIText-Bold", size: 14)!, range: (wholeStr as NSString).range(of: personName))
```

Comment: very easy to understand. nice answer

Comment: @Vats Welcome & Thanks :)

Comment: Might wanna change `value: UIFont(name: "SFUIText-Bold", size: 14)!` to `value: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)` - pretty sure the former will crash at runtime (force-unwrapping a nil optional).

Comment: @worthbak Thanks for the suggestion mate :), but this question about `addAttribute` and range