# Calculate range of string from word to end of string in swift

Tags: swift, nsrange

I have an NSMutatableString:

```
var string: String = "Due in %@ (%@) $%@.\nOverdue! Please pay now %@"
attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string, attributes: attributes)
```

How to calculate both the length and starting index from the word `Overdue` in swift?

so far I have tried:

```
let startIndex = attributedText.string.rangeOfString("Overdue")
let range = startIndex..<attributedText.string.finishIndex

// Access the substring.
let substring = value[range]
print(substring)
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should generate the resulting string first:

```
let string = String(format: "Due in %@ (%@) $%@.\nOverdue! Please pay now %@", "some date", "something", "15", "some date")
```

Then use `.disTanceTo` to get the distance between indices;

```
if let range = string.rangeOfString("Overdue") {
  let start = string.startIndex.distanceTo(range.startIndex)
  let length = range.startIndex.distanceTo(string.endIndex)

  let wordToEndRange = NSRange(location: start, length: length) 
  // This is the range you need

  attributedText.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, 
     value: UIColor.blueColor(), range: wordToEndRange)
}
```

[image]

---

Please do note that `NSRange` does not work correctly if the string contains Emojis or other Unicode characters so that the above solution may not work properly for that case.

Please look at the following SO answers for a better solution which cover that case as well:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/27041376/793428
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/27880748/793428

Comment: Genius. Solved 2 of my problems by adding the color. Thank you so much @ozgur! Wish I could double up vote.

Comment: This conversion of string indices to NSRange does *not* work correctly if the string contains Emojis or other Unicode characters > U+FFFF. Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27880650/swift-extract-regex-matches  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27040924/nsrange-from-swift-range for similar issues. – You can try it with `let string = " Bla bla Overdue! bla bla"`

Answer (score 0):

Look at this,

```
                let nsString = element.text as NSString
                let range = nsString.range(of: word, options: .widthInsensitive)
                let att: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.systemBlue]
                attText.addAttributes(att, range: NSRange(location: range.location, length: range.length))
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. Why do you think your proposed solution might help the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Base of the Mahadev Prabhu's answer:

```
extension String {
    func getRange(of word: String)-> NSRange {
        return (self as NSString).range(of: word, options: .widthInsensitive)
    }
}
```