# How to convert Range<String.Index> to NSRange?

Tags: ios, swift, string, range

How do I convert `Range<String.Index>` to `NSRange` in Swift (< 4) without first converting the `String` to an `NSString`?

The reason I want to do this is that I want to set a `UITextView`'s `selectedText` property using a `Range<String.Index>` value.

Alternative solution: How do I set `UITextInput.selectedTextRange` with a `Range<String.Index>` value?

Comment: Dupe?   [NSRange from Swift Range?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27040924/2415822).  Any reason you don't want to bridge to NSString?  Also, there are some non-NSString solutions in the answers to that question.

Comment: Bridging to `NSString` doesn't seem pure, intuitive, understandable, self-documenting, readable, simple, beautiful, or efficient. None of the non-`NSString` solutions to that question work for strings that contain emojis.

Answer (score 10):

Use String.Index's samePosition(in:) method with the string's UTF16 view. NSString uses UTF16, so the UTF16 indexes should be identical to the indexes NSString expects for the NSRange.

EDIT:

```
public extension NSRange {
    private init(string: String, lowerBound: String.Index, upperBound: String.Index) {
        let utf16 = string.utf16

        let lowerBound = lowerBound.samePosition(in: utf16)
        let location = utf16.distance(from: utf16.startIndex, to: lowerBound)
        let length = utf16.distance(from: lowerBound, to: upperBound.samePosition(in: utf16))

        self.init(location: location, length: length)
    }

    public init(range: Range<String.Index>, in string: String) {
        self.init(string: string, lowerBound: range.lowerBound, upperBound: range.upperBound)
    }

    public init(range: ClosedRange<String.Index>, in string: String) {
        self.init(string: string, lowerBound: range.lowerBound, upperBound: range.upperBound)
    }
}
```

Comment: It wasn't marked as a duplicate when I was writing the answer. Looks like the duplicate mark squeaked in right before I submitted it.

Comment: Well, I prefer your answer to any of the others. Could you provide the code for a method that I could call like: `NSRange(range, in: string)`?

Comment: I used to have just such a method, actually. I deleted it when I upgraded all my code to Swift 4, but I could probably dig it out of the git repository. Unfortunately, it'll have to wait a few days because my development machine is in the shop taking way too long to get a swollen battery replaced. Remember when we used to be able to just pop the old one out and the new one in? Nowadays you're stuck without your laptop for a week, it seems.

Comment: Finally got it back. Adding it as an edit.

Comment: It seems like a straightforward and robust solution. But after testing it, I got a mismatch, when replacing a substring using converted NSRange.
In the Swift Language Guide, there is a note about it:
"The count of the characters returned by the count property isn't always the same as the length property of an NSString that contains the same characters. The length of an NSString is based on the number of 16-bit code units within the string’s UTF-16 representation and not the number of Unicode extended grapheme clusters within the string."