# After upgrade to Xcode Version 10.2 (10E125),Fatal error when using range.upperBound.samePosition(in: utf16)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5

After upgrade to Xcode Version 10.2 (10E125),
progress Fatal error at `range.upperBound.samePosition(in: utf16)`

```
extension String {

    //Range => NSRange
    func nsRange(from range: Range<String.Index>) -> NSRange {
        guard let to = range.upperBound.samePosition(in: utf16) else {
            return NSMakeRange(0, 0)
        }

        guard let from = range.lowerBound.samePosition(in: utf16) else {
            return NSMakeRange(0, 0)
        }

        return NSMakeRange(utf16.distance(from: utf16.startIndex, to: from), utf16.distance(from: from, to: to))
    }

    //NSRange =>Range
    func range(from range: NSRange) -> Range<String.Index>? {
        guard let from16 = utf16.index(utf16.startIndex, offsetBy: range.location, limitedBy: utf16.endIndex) else { return nil }
        guard let to16 = utf16.index(from16, offsetBy: range.length, limitedBy: utf16.endIndex) else { return nil }
        guard let from = String.Index(from16, within: self) else { return nil }
        guard let to = String.Index(to16, within: self) else { return nil }
        return from ..< to
    }
}
```

it start crash in

> range.upperBound.samePosition(in: utf16)

error

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

I expect good running

image:  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfbbf.png

Comment: Where does `utf16` come from?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert Range<String.Index> to NSRange?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45493826/how-to-convert-rangestring-index-to-nsrange)

Comment: I use this code in extension of String, so utf16 possible is self.utf16, I did see there answer,it run good before Xcode 10.2, but  After upgrade to Xcode Version 10.2 (10E125), progress Fatal error

Comment: But you don’t need any of your code, because string conversion between range and NSRange is now built in

Comment: thanks a lot ,conversion between range and NSRange already built in after swift4