# Emoji loss when using NSMutableAttributedString on UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring

I have got some strange problem while using NSMutableAttributedString for setting text part on UILabel. It shows some bizarre symbol for specific emojis. Here's the code i use and the screenshot of the problem.

```
guard var _comment = comment.comment ,let _username = comment.userName else { return }
var username = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: _username)
var commentText = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: _comment)
var commentTotal = NSMutableAttributedString.init()
commentTotal.append(username)
commentTotal.append(commentText)
self.userNameLabel.attributedText = commentTotal
```

Screenshot :

[image]

But if i directly put the string without using NSMutableAttributedString like this:

```
self.userName.text = _comment
```

The output of this shows the correct emoji without problem
.What would be the problem here? Anyone with a suggestion? 
[image]

This is the code for setting fonts :

```
if let font = UIFont.init(name: "Montserrat-Bold", size: self.userNameLabel.font.pointSize){
        username.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: font, range: NSRange.init(location: 0, length: _username.count))
        username.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.init(red: 0/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1.0), range: NSRange.init(location: 0, length: _username.count))
    }



if let font = UIFont.init(name: "Montserrat-Medium", size: self.userNameLabel.font.pointSize-1){
                    commentText.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: font, range: NSRange.init(location: 0, length: commentString.count))
                    commentText.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.init(red: 0/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1.0), range: NSRange.init(location: 0, length: commentString.count))
                }
```

Storyboard Image:
[image]

Comment: That's probably because you are setting the (not a) wrong font family to the attributed string or UILabel.

Comment: What are the strings `_username` and `_comment`? A *self-contained* reproducible example would be helpful.

Comment: @MartinR  _comment  : "" and username = "canhamzacan"

Comment: @ElTomato I updated the question for more information about fonts. I use different font family and font size for different part of the string. Is it because of that?

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks a lot for help. i couldnt search it with right words.

Comment: Related: [NSRange from Swift Range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27040924/nsrange-from-swift-range)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your problem is with your `NSRange` calculations when setting the attributes. `NS[Mutable]AttributeString` needs the `NSRange` to be based on `NSString` ranges, not `String` ranges.

So code like:

```
NSRange.init(location: 0, length: commentString.count)
```

Needs to be written as either:

```
NSRange(location: 0, length: (commentString as NSString).length)
```

or:

```
NSRange(location: 0, length: commentString.utf16.count)
```

The following demonstrates the issue with `commentString.count`:

```
let comment = ""
print(comment.count) // 3
print((comment as NSString).length) // 6
print(comment.utf16.count) // 6
```

This is why your code seems to be splitting the middle character in half. You are passing in half (in this case) the needed length.

Comment: Bravo. It helps me a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Proper way to do this in Swift 4 is using indexes on `String`:

```
NSRange(location: 0, length: commentString.endIndex.encodedOffset)
```

Comment: Interesting. `String.Index encodedOffset` is based on the UTF-16 encoded string. So `string.endIndex.encodedOffset` will be the same as `string.utf16.count`.