# Why does my playground crash on NSRange()

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring, nsrange, nsmutableattributedstring

I'm trying to learn about `NSMutableAttributedString` and `NSAttributedString` so I've created a simple playground to try some things. However, I have a couple of issues I can't figure out even after looking at a lot of examples on SO (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24666515/how-do-i-make-an-attributed-string-using-swift/32269975#32269975) and [NSRange from Swift Range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27040924/nsrange-from-swift-range)and) elsewhere.

The problem is with the length property. If I specify the length as `attribLabelText.length` it causes an uncaught exception. If I specify `attribLabelText.length - 1` there's no error, but only the letters 'Repor' have the attributes I'm setting:

[image]

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        let label = getLabel1(labelText: "Report")
        view.addSubview(label)
        self.view = view
    }
}

func getLabel1(labelText: String) -> UILabel {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 200, width: 200, height: 20)
    label.textColor = .black

    let attribLabelText: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: labelText)
    let attributes = [
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.gray.cgColor,
        NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
        ] as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]

    attribLabelText.addAttributes(attributes, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attribLabelText.length)) <-- this causes an uncaught exception of type NSException

    label.attributedText = attribLabelText

    return label
}
// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

I have a feeling this is going to be something obvious but I'm out of ideas to try. Can anybody point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You should be passing a `UIColor` for the foreground color, not a `CGColor`

Comment: @dan - I was about to tell you, "Thanks, but that has nothing to do with my question" and then I changed `UIColor.gray.cgColor` to `UIColor.gray` and it fixed the NSRange problem. So, thanks, but could you a) make it an answer so I can accept it and b) explain why this worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be passing a `UIColor` for the foreground color instead of a `CGColor`.

UILabel seems to use the foreground color attribute slightly differently when drawing the string based on whether the attribute covers the entire range of the string or just a subrange.

The version it uses when the attribute covers the entire string only works with `UIColor` but the version it uses when the attribute only covers a substring seems to also work with `CGColor` (though this behavior isn't documented so it shouldn't be relied on) which explains why adding the -1 to the range avoids the exception.