# How to generate NSRange correctly for a given String to represent end of String?

Tags: ios, swift

Currently, my app is using `NSRange` in our data model, to represent the cursor position in `UITextView`.

Sometimes, we will generate `NSRange` to represent end of position/ end of string in `UITextView`.

This is our code to generate `NSRange`.

```
extension NSRange {
    static func endOfStringFocused(_ string: String?) -> NSRange {
        return NSRange(location: string?.count ?? 0, length: 0)
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        textView.selectedRange = NSRange.endOfStringFocused(textView.text)
        textView.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

This is the outcome, when there is no emoji in the string. It works as expected because the cursor is now at the end of the string.

[image]

However, when there is non-english character (emoji) used, the outcome is incorrect. The cursor is no longer at the end of the string.

[image]

May I know, how to generate `NSRange` correctly for a given String to represent end of String?

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30404532/1187415

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways. I recommend making a Swift `Range<String.Index>`, and convert it to an `NSRange`:

```
NSRange(string.endIndex..., in: string)
```

See also: [NSRange from Swift Range?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27040924/5133585)

The reason why the incorrect behaviour happens, is because the `location` property in `NSRange` counts a different thing (UTF-16 code units) than what the Swift `String.count` property counts (the number of Swift `Character`s, which are extended grapheme clusters, in the string). Therefore, to fix this, we can also just pass the correct number to `NSRange(location:length:)`:

```
NSRange(location: string.utf16.count, length: 0)
// or
NSRange(location: (string as NSString).length, length: 0)
```

But I find these less intuitive than just converting the Swift range to `NSRange`.