# Adding font size and custom font name to attributed string in UITextView

Tags: ios, swift3, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I have the following code to add the attributed string to the UITextView text. I need to add the custom font and font size to it in swift. How to do it?

```
    func setAttributedString(string: String) -> NSAttributedString {
    let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string)
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 7
    paragraphStyle.minimumLineHeight = 7
    attrString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSRange(location: 0, length:attrString.length))
    attrString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30), range: NSRange(location: 0, length:attrString.length))
    return attrString
  }
```

I need to add the custom font and font size to the following function. How to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make an attributed string using Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24666515/how-do-i-make-an-attributed-string-using-swift)

Comment: You will hopefully get your answer from link. Just convert syntax to latest swift syntax.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46460034/swift-3-render-textview-using-nsattributedstring-but-want-change-the-default-fon/46460119#46460119

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 3

```
let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 17)!, 
              NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]

let attributedString  = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Your string" , attributes: attributes)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the initializer init(string:attributes:)

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/1408136-init

```
let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string, attributes:
            [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(
            name: "Georgia",
            size: 18.0)!])
    //Add more attributes here
```