# How to set a different font size just for UITextView's first line of?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I got a `UItextView`, I want the first line of its content to have larger size than the rest.
Like the following image.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jw46z.png)
But I don't see any font size related attribute in paragraph attributes.
So, how to do that?
Thanks for any advices.

Comment: Use AttributedString

Comment: @MahendraGP But the UITextView is dynamic. The content is allowed editing.

Comment: @MahendraGP Dynamically Change the attributes in the delegate method doesn't feel like a good method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Example of NSAttributedString with two different font sizes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365631/example-of-nsattributedstring-with-two-different-font-sizes)

Answer (score 0):

Use NSMutableAttributedString..

```
            NSMutableAttributedString *firstLine = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"First Line\n" attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20]}];

            NSAttributedString *secondLine = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"Second Line" attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16]}];

            [firstLine appendAttributedString:secondLine];
            yourTextView.attributedText = firstLine;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried attributed String? You just need to know how long your first line will be.

```
// 16.0 is your standard font size for the textView
let text = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "your whole text for the textview", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16.0)])
// 23.0 is the size for your first line
text.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.font, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 23.0), range: NSRange(location: 0, length: firstLineLength))

textView.attributedText = text
```

Answer (score 0):

Select your label then tap on the **attributes inspector** .

Select the **Attributed**

[image]

You will see the changes just like this -

[image]

Select the first line just like -

[image]

Then tap on the text icon

[image]-

Now change the font and press enter after that, changes will trigger in your stroyboard label. Do same for others.
[image]